# Problems with Python Matplotlib ---- Only part of plot is drawn

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a program to plot probability mass function of Poisson Distribution. It works well when the distribution parameter lambda (variable a in the program) is small (<=707). But problem occurs when `a` is large (for example, `a=1000`).

The x-axis is supposed to be drawn from `0` to `a*3`, but it stops at approximately 800 when `a=1000`. Why does this happen and how to solve it?

This is the result when a=7 **----No problem----**
[image: Figure_1]

This is the result when a=707 **----No problem----**
[image: Figure_2]

And this is the result when a=708  **----x-axis is supposed to be drawn to 2124, but it stops at 708----**

[image: Figure_3]

Code:

```py
from math import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[]
y=[]

def f(i, a):
    p=1
    for t in range(1,i+1):
        p=p*a/t
    return exp(-a)*p

def poisson():
    a=input("lambda:  ")
    a=int(a)
    for i in range(a*3):
        x.append(i)
        #y.append(exp(-a)*(a**i)/factorial(i)) ------1-------
        y.append(f(i,a))   #The same result as ------1-------. Use this instead in order to avoid the error "int is too large to be converted to float" when a is large.
    #plt.xlim([0,2000])  tried but the graph stops at 708 as well
    plt.scatter(x,y)


poisson()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I observe the `p` variable becomes too large and it becomes `inf`, here I added a print function inside your `f()`:

```py
def f(i, a):
    p=1
    for t in range(1,i+1):
        p=p*a/t
    print(p, i) # print the values
    return exp(-a)*p
```

If you run the program with `lambda = 708` you will get the result:

```
1 0
708.0 1
250632.0 2
59149152.0 3
...
2.3276264191758687e+305 677
2.430618738608429e+305 678
2.534430142761072e+305 679
2.63878903099241e+305 680
inf 681
inf 682
inf 683
...
inf 2122
inf 2123
```

As you can see the `p` variable grows exponentially (or worse, factorially) and it becomes too large so python converts it to `inf`. Because of this, the rest of `y = exp(-a)*p` when `p` is `inf` results in `inf`, that's why the scatterplot stops at 680 because matplotlib cant plot `inf` values.

Comment: Thanks. It may be solved by dividing p by e in time, though this will make the algorithm more complex.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
from math import exp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[]
y=[]

def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n > 0:
        return factorial(n-1)*n

def f(i, a):
    return exp(-a)*(a**i/factorial(i))

def poisson():
    a=input("lambda:  ")
    a=int(a)
    for i in range(a*3):
        x.append(i)
        #y.append(exp(-a)*(a**i)/factorial(i)) ------1-------
        y.append(f(i,a))   #The same result as ------1-------. Use this instead in order to avoid the error "int is too large to be converted to float" when a is large.
    #plt.xlim([0,2000])  tried but the graph stops at 708 as well
    plt.scatter(x,y)


poisson()
plt.show()
```